# Algorithms for: printer checker

Tags: image-processing, printing, computer-vision

I want to make a program for checking the printed paper for errors.

[PDF File: please refer to the second page, top right picture](http://www.lvs-inc.com/ContentPDFS/data_lvs7500.pdf)

As you see, that system could identify the errors made by printer. 
I want to know how was it achieved. What are existing documents about this? 
Or any ideas you have?
Thank you

Comment: I assume they have a patent on their approach. Therefore, find the patent and read it.

Comment: @zerm Yes it is written there about pending patent. How to find the patent by company name?

Comment: @erjik try google patent search: http://www.google.com/patents
also helpful, just search for company, or names of engineers. may take a while to find the right one. If you have money to spend, I guess you can hire some lawyer for this. You can contact the company as well and simply ask for it. If you manage to find it, would be nice if you could report back here.

Comment: @erjik ok, as it's still pending, maybe google does not have it yet. You can still ask at the company. As a starting point, however, I found this older old from that company: http://www.google.com/patents/about?id=LxoFAAAAEBAJ
Maybe this is already helpful?

Comment: @zerm thank you very much!!
I think I can wait for some time. Until the patent will be published...

Comment: @zerm is it possible to search for pending patents?

Comment: @erjik honestly, I do not know. I just know that getting a patent accepted and published might take a year or even longer. You can ask the company, if they have submitted the patent, they have nothing to fear. Maybe you can find some place where to ask this questions, I dont know much about patents and few people on SO will. I just figured out myself several things by reading the patents ;)

Answer (score 1):

This can be very easy or very difficult. 
if your images are black white and your scan is quite precise you can try with a simple subtraction between the images (scanned and pattern)
if your scan will read the image with a possible deformation or translation the you will need first an image registration algorithm.
if your scan present background noise you will have some trouble with the subtraction and then it turns very difficult. 
may be some image samples can help to suggest you a more specific algorithm.

Comment: The original image is black and white, but scan image is grayscale. One more thing is that image can be deformed by printer if the paper goes inside with some mistake. One more problem, the paper on which the image is printed can already contain something printed on it. How to deal with that?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to some how compare two images in a way that is robust to deformation. As mentioned before, substracting the two images can be a first step. Another more sophisticated way can be to use [distance transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_transform) (or chamfering based methods for template matching) to compare how similar the two images are in the presence of some deformation. More sophisticated solutions can use methods like [shape contexts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shape_context).